# Solr Term Proximity function for the solrconfig.xml

Tags: xml, search, solr, full-text-search

I need to use the **Solr Term Proximity for all my queries**.

**Example:**
I enter the query `pc 18`.
What I want now is Solr to search for `pc OR 18 OR "pc 18"~10^10`.

Is there a way to define the Term Proximity in the `solrconfig.xml` to make the server "convert" all my queries?

Answer (score 0):

The [(e)dismax handler supports setting static proximity](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_search_for_one_term_near_another_term_.28say.2C_.22batman.22_and_.22movie.22.29) values through phrase slop and phrase fields:

```
q=batman movie&pf=text&ps=100
```

You can set these values as static values in your solrconfig.xml for the requestHandler, or you can just include them in the query URL outside of the actual query.

Comment: but this does not work like i want. I need to specify the relevance of the whole search term in my solrconfig.xml

Comment: @DennisKonoppa As mentioned, you can set these as static values in your solrconfig.xml. You'll add them as `<lst>`'s of values, where each section can [define a parameter as as a default value, a value appended to the query or as a invariant](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SearchHandler#Configuration) (can't be changed by a client). Which is what you wanted, right?